Goalkeeper gets assist. Unusual
Goalkeeper plays ball out to striker who lets ball bounce and scores with first touch. Saw this at the weekend. Can’t remember seeing this before even though I’ve seen keepers score directly. This must have happened surely? Thanks.

A trivial amount of research shows this happens a few times a year; for example using the Premier League's stats page and selecting position = Goalkeeper gives:

One so far this season (2024-5)
Two in the 2023-4 season
Four in 2022-3
Three in 2021-2
[...]
Eight in 1992-3

and so on. I'm sure the same happens in other top leagues.
